# Combine text contents of two cells ONLY if one has an entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to copy the contents of two cells as an easy "cheat" to be able to copy the text for entry somewhere else.

The first cell (D2) is a name. Example: `Smith, John`

The second cell (AG2) is a note. Example: `Paid 08/31`

The result I want would look like: `Smith, John Paid 08/31`

BUT I only want this new cell to populate if cell AG2 has an entry.  (I don't want my whole column clogged up with names that have no note to go along with them.)

I would also like to know how to insert a couple spaces between each piece of copied information, so it's not all crammed together.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AG2),"",D2&" "&AG2)
```

The `IF` checks if `AG2` is blank. If `TRUE` (AG2 is blank), it returns blank (“”). If `FALSE` (AG2 is not blank), it returns the combination of `D2` and `AG2` separated by a space. You can add as many strings you like using the `&` symbol. You can point to a cell or type your string surrounded by `“`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you - couldn't get the syntax quite right. :))

Comment: @HallyBashor if it works, please mark as accepted.